Restarting tomcat server in cpanel
When I run /usr/local/cpanel/scripts/ea-tomcat85 all restart, it returns
Starting sojrelites …
Restarting ea-tomcat85... May 27, 2024 11:10:09 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina stopServer
SEVERE: No shutdown port configured. Shut down server through OS signal. Server not shut down.
restarted
… done (sojrelites).
However, when I run ubic status ea-tomcat, the tomcat is not running.
I am trying to run spring boot war file on vps. I am using ea-tomcat85 with apache4. I have followed all steps from documentation here. Any help will be appreciated.
